# Should we use Solidity style overflow checks ( a * b / b == a) in Rust, or native checked operations like checked_mul()?

Tags: rust, solidity, integer-overflow

Solidity does not have native overflow checks. We can implement a custom multiply check for `a * b` by checking whether `a * b / b == a`.

```
uint256 product = a * b;
if (product / b == a) {
    // No overflow
} else {
    // Handle overflow
}
```

What are the trade-offs in solidity style vs idomatic rust style (`checked_mul()`)? This is a smart contract so I want to optimize for performance. Solidity style panics in debug mode due to overflow checks, so I am forced to test in release.

#### Solidity style

```rs
let product = a * b;
if product / b == a {
    // No overflow
} else {
    // Handle overflow
}
```

#### Rust idiomatic style

```rs
match a.checked_mul(b) {
    Some(product) => todo!("No overflow"),
    None => todo!("Handle overflow"),
}
```

Comment: I would expect `checked_mul()` to offer the best performance for the underlying platform. The advantage of using it in both debug and release mode is obvious, so I'd go with the solidity-style checks only if benchmarking shows it to be significantly more efficient.

Comment: checked_mul is on most implementation a bitflag check, so you can't have faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, always assume the standard library has the best implementation possible unless benchmarking show otherwise. In this case, the `checked_mul()` method is [implemented via an intrinsic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/num/int_macros.rs.html#1440), and you'll hardly get something better. You can see that it compiles down to a simple check of the overflow flag on x86, for example: https://rust.godbolt.org/z/rGrdfab7a.

Also, what if `a` is zero? This will panic, and even if this case is invalid for you, the compiler is still forced to handle it: https://rust.godbolt.org/z/Gnax6z5x9.

Even if you help the optimizer, it seems LLVM is unable to optimize this pattern: https://rust.godbolt.org/z/4xq97WxcT.

So, just use `checked_mul()`.

Answer (score 3):

I would say to use the idiomatic approach for this. Simply because of the ergonomics and already made implementations that exist on checked operations. And about performance, I would say to trust the compiler, then benchmark it if you're still unsure.